# ANSI Escape Sequences

Tags: terminal, telnet, ansi-escape

I need help identifying what these ANSI escape sequences represent. I'm currently filtering/evaluating the ANSI codes in a terminal screen reader I'm writing, but I'm not sure what these are.

Escape Sequences:

[0;1mm

[0;1;;4m

I'm using the below chart of escape sequences as reference:
http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm) is the primary source of these.

As to your specific examples:

```
[0;1mm
```

Is SGR (select graphic rendition) 0 and 1, followed by a normal unescaped `m`. SGR 0 resets all the rendition attributes, 1 enables bold.

```
[0;1;;4m
```

Is SGR 0, 1, 4. 0 resets, 1 enables bold, 4 enables single underline.

---

EDIT: Actually, I believe this second example is equivalent to

```
CSI 0;1;0;4 m
```

which resets, enables bold, resets a second time, then enables underline. So overall, only enables underline, not bold.

Comment: Many appreciations. Still catching hold of all the escape sequence meanings.

Comment: Note that if you’re trying to understand codes being written to a terminal, using several documentation sources will usually be helpful, to find codes that aren’t part of specific standards or supported by a particular (hardware) terminal or emulator. Also note the ECMA-48 standard describes several codes that aren’t supported by some popular terminal emulators, because the standard is meant to be comprehensive and describes some esoteric or market-specific features.

Answer (score 1):

The chart you linked to is strictly the codes supported by the VT100 terminal (and the subset supported by VT52). Go to the [ANSI Escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) chart right next to that one to see the ANSI terminal codes chart, which explains the `ESC [ … m` sequence. (Those pages are a little confusing about which chart they’re displaying.)

The executive summary is that the codes you posted enable bold and underlined text.

I also recommend the [Xterm supported codes](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) chart, which covers codes supported by Xterm and a few other common terminal emulators, as well as some other hardware terminals.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to the escape sequences so it's all unforged steel to me.